# How to override C-x in neovim

Tags: neovim

Need to close buffer by C-x:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-x>', '<Cmd>BufferClose<CR>', {})
```

When I press C-x neovim open explore(netrw).

How I can override default C-x behavior?

Comment: What does `:map <C-x>` say?

Comment: Exactly, I found what the problem was. Thank you.

Comment: Please post how you solved it to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Command for help:

```
:map <C-x>
```

For close buffer(ctrl+x) and reopen(shift+ctrl+x) :

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-x>', '<Cmd>BufferClose<CR>', {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-S-x>', '<Cmd>BufferRestore<CR>', {})
```

In alacrity.yml:

```
key_bindings:
  - { key: X,        mods: Control|Shift, chars: "\x1b[88;5u" }
```

ASCII Table for find a char code: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html?viewsel=on